# Prove the improper integral is absolutely convergent

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(\sec(x))dx$$

This is what I come up with:
Let $ \sec x=\frac{1}{t}, \cos x=\frac{1}{t} $, $x=\arccos\frac{1}{t}$, so
$dx = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{t^2}}}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt$
   $= \frac{1}{t\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt.$
Then when $x=0, t=1; x=\frac{\pi}{2}, t=+\infty $

Comment: Please use Mathjax. You have been here for 7 months.

Comment: I rolled back the previous edit because it deleted important information from the title, namely that all you want here is to prove the integral converges.

Comment: is the answer $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Monocerotis, how could the answer be $\pi/2$, since $\sin(\sec x)\lt1$ for most values of $x$?

Comment: If you don't see what you did wrong, it would make sense to post it as its own question (with a link here to help provide context). I'm not sure what you mean about a pole at zero; the only pole I see is at $x=\pi/2$, where $\sec x$ goes to infinity. But I think the function $\sin(\sec x)$ may have an essential singularity there. (I'm not positive about this; it's been decades since I studied complex analysis.)

Comment: I had taken the wrong limit of the integral so nvm

Answer (score 5):

Even though $\sec x\to\infty$ as $x\to\pi/2$, this is not actually an improper integral, because $\sin(\sec x)$ is *bounded* in the *finite* interval $[0,\pi/2]$. (An integral is only improper if one or both of its limits is at infinity, or if the integrand is unbounded.) What we have here is

$$\left|\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\sec x)\,dx \right|\le\int_0^{\pi/2}|\sin(\sec x)|\,dx\le\int_0^{\pi/2}dx=\pi/2$$

You can, of course, *change* it into an improper integral with the substitution you came up with: Letting $\sec x=t$ (not $1/t$), we wind up with

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\sec x)\,dx =\int_1^\infty{\sin t\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$$

and the latter is improper at both limits, $1$ (because of the $t^2-1$) and $\infty$.

Comment: (+1) At first, I saw the last line, which I knew came from the arcsec substitution, and missed the simpler solution above it. I even wrote an answer using the simple inequality in the first line, but deleted it when I realized you had already given it.

Answer (score 1):

Taking off from where Barry left off,we get the original integral as

$\int_1^\infty{\sin t\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$ which is clearly lesser than

$\int_0^\infty{\sin t\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$ as sin(x)>0 in the interval (0,1)

now, 
$\int_0^\infty{\sin t\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt$ =1/2$Re(\int_{-\infty}^\infty{{e^{it}}\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt)$

[image]

now we take the following curve in the complex plane and apply Cauchy's theorem.

the integral over the semicircular arc vanishes and we are left with
$0=\oint_C f(z)\,dz=\int_{-R}^\epsilon f(x)\,dz-\int_{\gamma_\epsilon} f(z)\,dz+\int_\epsilon^R f(x)\,dx+\int_{\gamma_Rf(z)dz}$

now using the substitution

$\gamma(x)={\lim _{h\to 0}he^{ix}}.$

$\int_{\gamma_\epsilon}|{e^{ihe^{ix}}hie^{ix}\pi\over 2he^{ix}\sqrt{{(he^{ix})}^2-1}}\,| \,dz$=$\frac{h\pi i}{2hi}$

we find that integral equals to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

so we conclude that

$\int_1^\infty{\sin t\over t\sqrt{t^2-1}}dt$<$\frac{\pi}{2}$